# Why did one mod close this question on removing the password on several RAR files at once as a duplicate?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The question [How can I remove the password on several RAR files at once?](https://superuser.com/q/1763068/116475) was closed by 1 mod as a duplicate of [Can I remove a RAR file's (known) password without recompressing the archive?](https://superuser.com/q/329874/116475). Why?

The OP stated they need to batch process and don't care if it gets recompressed, [Can I remove a RAR file's (known) password without recompressing the archive?](https://superuser.com/q/329874/116475) doesn't address.

The only comment from the mod who closed the question was:

> "I need to batch process" so write a script. [DavidPostill](https://superuser.com/users/337631/davidpostill)**♦** [yesterday](https://superuser.com/questions/1763068/how-can-i-remove-the-password-on-several-rar-files-at-once#comment2742124_1763068)

which doesn't explain the closure as a duplicate, and "write a script" doesn't sound like a reason to close.

Comment: This question would have been closed regardless if the user who cast the vote was a moderator or not, since they also have a gold badge for the tag. Why are you writing this question making it unclear it was your question that was closed?

Comment: You disputed the duplicate and said you wanted a batch process, ie a script or batch file.

Comment: With your rep and time on the site you should be aware that http://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://meta.superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill "Why are you writing this question making it unclear it was your question that was closed?" not making things personal.

Comment: @DavidPostil so it has nothing to do with a dupe?

Comment: [Question is in the reopen queue.](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/1167325), I don’t really consider it ready to be reopened, but you clearly feel it is. You still have shared what you have tried.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Batch processing doesn't imply scripting e.g. https://superuser.com/a/726429/116475.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Many questions on SU don't specify which programs to use e.g. https://superuser.com/q/526275/116475

Comment: @Giacomo1968 "Please don’t take post closing so personally" I'm not, why do you think that? ; "perhaps learn something from the experience" hence this meta Q, but I'm not getting clear answers: at first, it's a dupe, then lack of research, then a scripting request, then a software request etc. etc.; "it seems like this isn’t the first time someone is stating your posts are off-topic" not surprising since I asked >5k Qs. ; "That question is from Dec 31, 2012"  ok here's a recent one: https://superuser.com/q/1685218/116475

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Many non-closed questions here ask to achieve some actions without specifying which program they want to use, so it is far from an exception.  Anyway, if I change my question to "How can I remove the password on several RAR files at once with WinRAR?", is that on-topic?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 so we're both confused as to what is on-topic here.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 just trying to understand the close reason.

Comment: "Anyway, if I change my question to "How can I remove the password on several RAR files at once with WinRAR?", is that on-topic?" It is, but that interpretation would be a duplicate ...

Comment: You question is off topic for a variety of different reasons depending on how it is interpreted. We are just wasting time discussing what the exact close message should be.

Comment: @DavidPostill what's left to interpretation in "How can I remove the password on several RAR files at once?"

Comment: Nothing left to interpret. But it is a duplicate. Of [Can I remove a RAR file's (known) password without recompressing the archive? - Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/329874/can-i-remove-a-rar-files-known-password-without-recompressing-the-archive). That covers a single RAR file. You have to write a script for multiple RAR files. We don't write scripts. What is it about this that you don't understand?

Comment: @DavidPostill Batch processing doesn't imply scripting e.g. https://superuser.com/a/726429/116475, so I don't understand why you think it's a script request. Also, plenty of answers on SU are scripts, so I don't understand why you say we don't write scripts. "Superusers" write scripts.

Comment: "Superusers" write scripts - no we don't. We fix and/or improve scripts that are provided by the OP. You haven't provided one.

Comment: [How can I test all zip files in a folder to verify if they are corrupted or not?](https://superuser.com/a/726429) is a **5 year old** question. Now closed as "seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations"

Comment: @DavidPostill I was mentioning https://superuser.com/a/726429/116475 to show that batch processing doesn't imply scripting (in this case, testing several zip files at once). Many questions ask for how to do some actions that may be scriptable but the OP doesn't provide any script attempts.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt In all honestly I would have closed your question as "Needs details or clarity". There is absolutely no information on what you have tried beyond basically appealing for people to do your work for you. It would be nice for you to demonstrate your own effort solving your problem for once. I even linked to two distinct questions that could be bashed together into a solution, or at least the beginnings of one. It would be good to see your attempt. Multiple people have said that you should show your work on this.

Comment: @Mokubai "There is absolutely no information on what you have tried":  showing research is not a requirement according to https://meta.superuser.com/q/7829/116475

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I've posted ~600 questions on main SU, and ~10 questions on Meta SU about my questions getting closed over the past 9 years. Not that pushy IMHO. Anyway, the OP identity shouldn't impact the question treatment.

Comment: It may not be a hard "must have" requirement, but it is strongly encouraged by our help page [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) which says "Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? **Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself,** it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and above all, it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer!" Your questions are, by that point, often not "good" questions.

Comment: @Mokubai so if it's not a must-have requirements, then why is the question closed?

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt It is still closed because no one has voted to reopen it. It has been through the reopen queue and voted to be left closed and no community members believe you have made any effort to make it a worthwhile and useful question. None of the issues *anyone* has raised have been addressed by you so at this point it seems that the main person preventing it from being reopened is you.

Comment: By refusing to improve your question in any meaningful way and instead resorting to rule-lawyering you prove that this is less about the question itself, which you seemingly dont care about getting an answer to, and more about your right to ask zero effort questions in the first place. If you actually cared about the question you would actually engage with the community and help them to help you.

Comment: In complete honesty, I am curious enough that I *could* sit down and spend my own personal free time to work out the handful of lines that might be needed to vaguely achieve your goal, but what stops me is the fact that you see my time and effort as effectively worthless and somehow "beneath you", as evidenced by your personal lack of interest in showing us that this is something worth assisting with. You have already made up your mind that no one wants to help you and refuse to accept that getting help sometimes requires you to make the first step towards getting help.

Comment: @Mokubai since research is not a must-have requirement, the mod should not have closed the question in the first place. "None of the issues anyone has raised have been addressed by you": yes, the concerns were addressed: we clarified it's neither an app  request nor a script request. We also clarified that research is not a must-have requirement.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 "You seem more concerned about proving some philosophical point and “rule-lawyering”, No, I'm concerned about having clear close policies, and consistent applications of these policies.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - "Batch processing doesn't imply scripting" - It does. At least with regard to your question.  You can't perform a batch process to remove the password from a compressed archive without some sort of script that performs that task. In reality, what the duplicate indicates is that the password cannot be removed. The archive has to be decrypted with the password and recreated without a password.  **This explanation is converted in the answer to the duplicate.** Your question in my opinion show absolutely no research effort. Until such research is shared it cannot be answered.

Comment: @Ramhound "You can't perform a batch process to remove the password from a compressed archive without some sort of script that performs that task." Could be done via UI

Answer (score -4):

I'll summarize the close reasons I was told in the comment sections. Overall it seems everybody agrees it is not a duplicate.

Other mentioned close reasons:

1. The question is a software request. (Because the question doesn't specify which software to use, but many questions on SU also ask to perform some action without specifying the software).
2. The question is a script request. (The question can be answered without a script and many questions on SU can be answered with a script).
3. The question doesn't show any research. (Showing research is [not](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7829/116475) a requirement).

---

Here's an example of answer to the question showing that it's not a script request, assuming that both [7-Zip](https://www.7-zip.org/download.html) (gratis) and WinRAR are installed: Step 1: uncompress all RAR archives at once via 7-Zip, via right-click in explorer.exe -> `7-Zip->Extract to *\`.  Step 2: recompress each folder into their own RAR archive, via right-click in explorer.exe -> WinRAR -> checkbox "Put each file to separate archive".

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I am not showing any effort that is part of the “research” issue because it [isn't required](https://meta.superuser.com/q/7829/116475).

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt - If your takeaway from that meta question you linked to is that attempting to solve the problem yourself is not required and showing you attempted to solve the problem, then you have formed the same taken away as most people would.